# How to obtain mouse events from the kernel when X is active?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, input

When switching to a virtual terminal on my system, The kernel successfully delivers mouse events to a generic input event interface -`/dev/input/event6` in my case- as well as legacy interfaces `mouse1` and `mice`.

However, the kernel will completely fail to deliver mouse events to any of the aforementioned interfaces if the X server is active.

Is it at all possible to obtain raw mouse events when the X server is active without having to obtain the events through it? If so, how?

*(It should be noted that keyboard events are unaffected by the X server, and are successfully delivered regardless.)*

Comment: Do you have any files `/dev/input/mouse*`? On my system I can get mouse events on those as well as on `/dev/input/mice` (and X is running). I'm not sure why I do not get anything on `/dev/input/event*`.

Comment: Yes, I have `mouse0` and `mouse1`. Unfortunetly, neither will emit events when X is active.

Comment: Keyboard events are delivered as expected. (Regardless of whether X is active or not.)

Comment: Did you consider instead starting a terminal (e.g. `xterm`) under your X session?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Same result; keyboard events get delivered fine, and mouse events get blocked.

Comment: If two processes read from the same device, then some messages will be delivered on one process, and some to the other. You will have to add a message fork.